# SQL Server 2012 IO Latency and Wait Types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a system that has a resource intenstive houskeeping job. It hits two different data files on the same LUN. One is for relational data, one for blobs. During the job, read latency on the relational data file averages over 250ms, while on the LOB data it is only 5ms. This is measured using `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` (two samples 12 hours apart to encompass the houskeeping - during the other 12 hours, latency is 20ms).

I'm sampling wait stats using "who is active". In this I don't see any `PAGEIOLATCH` waits with large enough wait times to explain the 250ms. `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` backs this up with an average of 5ms for `PAGEIOLATCH_EX` and 15ms for `PAGEIOLATCH_SH`. What I do see is long waits for `LCK_M` (which is explainable, due to the nature of the housekeeping).

**My question** is: can the `LCK_M` waits contribute to the `io_stall_read_ms` times in the virtual file stats?

In case the details of the housekeeping matter, it is removing smallish batches of data using multiple cascading deltes, including ~1MB of LOB data per item. The system is using AlwaysOn with sync commit.

Comment: check out this post https://sqlperformance.com/2013/10/t-sql-queries/io-latency
Processing more data will lead to more latency, if your throughput goes up then this will be normal behavior.

Comment: @laurence answer to your question will by yes. io_stall_read_ms means Total time, in milliseconds, that the users waited for reads issued on the file and not the time it took to read the page from disk. For that you can use wmi counter avg. disk sec/read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The waits that are seen in `sys.dm_io_virtual_stats` are aggregates instead of point values. If you are doing a lot of transactions in a certain period, it will show you an higher aggregate --> higher average latency. More information on how this dmv works can be found on https://sqlperformance.com/2013/10/t-sql-queries/io-latency

> Virtual file stats are a great starting point when you want to
>   understand I/O performance for a SQL Server instance. If you see
>   I/O-related waits when looking at wait statistics, looking at
>   sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats is a logical next step. However,
>   understand that the data you're viewing is an aggregate since the
>   stats last cleared by one of the associated events (instance restart,
>   offline of database, etc).  If you see low latencies, then the I/O
>   subsystem is keeping up with the performance load. However, if you see
>   high latencies, it's not a foregone conclusion that storage is a
>   problem. To really know what's going on you can start to snapshot file
>   stats, as shown here, or you can simply use Performance Monitor to
>   look at latency in real time. It's very easy to create a Data
>   Collector Set in PerfMon that captures the Physical Disk counters Avg.
>   Disk Sec/Read and Avg. Disk Sec/Read for all disks that host database
>   files.

The `LCK_M` will not contribute to the `IO_STALL_READ_MS` as these counters are only IO related

Comment: This is very interesting but it doesn't answer the question. Can LCK_M waits contribute to the io_stall_read_ms. I've updated the question to make it clear the 250ms was measured as the difference between two 12hr samples. Should I expect the io_stall to correlate with IO type waits?

Comment: Yes, it will correlate only with the IO type waits

Comment: Thanks, Stijn. I've realised what the numbers indicate and answered myself. However, I'll mark yours as the answer as you answered the question I had correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've missed the obvious explanation.

`io_stall` measures difference between io being submitted and fulfilled. Wait stats only measure when a query doesn't have something useful to do.

The numbers I am seeing indicate:

1. IO latency has increased markedly as a result of the housekeeping load.
2. The housekeeping query can mostly find other useful work to do instead of waiting for IO to complete. (Else I would see high `PAGEIOLATCH` waits)